# How to best-fit a rational function approximation to Theodorsen's function using the lsqcurvefit function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting, function-approximation

I am using a rational function (polynomial ratio) to approximate Theodorsen's function. I am having issues in guessing the correct (most optimal) initial guess parameters using the lsqcurvefit function in Matlab. Is there a way to know what would be the best initial guess parameters to get the best fit result?

My code is the following:

```
k = logspace(-10,1,300);

% Exact Theodorsen's Function C(k) in terms of Bessel Function
Ck= @(k)(besselh(1,2,k))./(besselh(1,2,k)+1i*besselh(0,2,k));

% Ckget function used to extract real and imaginary numbers and stacks the result
Ckget= @(k)[real(Ck(k)); imag(Ck(k))]; 

% Define 3rd order approximation function 
x0= [.1,.1,.1,1,.1,.1,.1,.1]; % Create initial guess
U = 200;
b = 3;
s = 1i*k*(U/b);
Ck2 = @(x,k)((x(1)*s.^3 + x(2)*s.^2 + x(3)*s + x(4))./(x(5)*s.^3 + x(6)*s.^2 + x(7)*s + x(8)));
Ck2get= @(x,k)[real(Ck2(x,k)); imag(Ck2(x,k))]; %extract real & imaginary values

% Use curve fit function for best fit approximation
x2= lsqcurvefit(Ck2get,x0,k,Ckget(k))
```

Comment: I have had good experience using the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to create initial parameter estimates for non-linear fitting, if you can find this implemented in the MATrix LABoratory it is well worth trying.

Comment: @JamesPhillips would you mind sharing your work to get an idea of how this is done? Thanks.

Comment: No problem - my open source curve and fitting web site zunzun.com has source code links at the bottom of every page.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Great! where exactly I can find the initial parameter estimates for non-linear fitting resource?

Comment: The web site itself does not yield the intermediate initial parameter estimates. For that you need the fitting library source code, also linked to at the bottom of every page. The web site has a "function finder" for performing equation search among hundreds of equations if you simply need a smooth approximating equation rather than only this specific polynomial rational.

Comment: @JamesPhillips How do you use the following function:  `function [r,a,b,mu,nu,poles,residues] = padeapprox(f,m,n,tol)` I keep getting an 'out of memory error'

Comment: I do not use matlab, and so cannot answer the question. If you post this as a separate stackoverflow question you might get a good answer quickly.